# Retrieve child data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from my firebase, but i get null at the child items (latitude and longitude).

I don't know how to access those child items. I guess its problem with the  deserialize of jackson to java in my two classes (MyLatLng.class and Waypoints.class)

### -

**JSON STRUCTURE**

```
{
   "-KGRY2El-uvfSH3LKOLp" : {
     "Waypoints" : {
       "-KGRY2El-uvfSH3LKOLq" : {
         "latitude" : 223,
         "longitude" : 31
       },
       "-KGRY2El-uvfSH3LKOLr" : {
         "latitude" : 123,
         "longitude" : 23
       }
     },
     "timeStamp" : "2016/04/27 13:00:56"
   },
   "-KGRY2OhWFJ_1Zd9RDaU" : {
     "Waypoints" : {
       "-KGRY2OhWFJ_1Zd9RDaV" : {
         "latitude" : 223,
         "longitude" : 31
  },
  "-KGRY2OquKzf1EhmLpTl" : {
    "latitude" : 123,
    "longitude" : 23
  }
 },
   "timeStamp" : "2016/04/27 13:00:57"
 }
}
```

**Logcat with the error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar.Data.Waypoints.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
at com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar.MapListActivity$1.populateViewHolder(MapListActivity.java:49)

at com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar.MapListActivity$1.populateViewHolder(MapListActivity.java:41)
at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:191)
```

**PARENT FILE**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyLatLng {

@JsonProperty("timeStamp")
private String timeStamp;

@JsonProperty("waypoints")
private Map<String, Waypoints> waypoints;

public MyLatLng(String timeStamp, HashMap<String, Waypoints> waypoints)          {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.waypoints = waypoints;
}

public MyLatLng() {}

public String getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public Map<String, Waypoints> getWaypoints() {
    return waypoints;
}

public void setWaypoints(Map<String, Waypoints> waypoints) {
    this.waypoints = waypoints;
 }
}
```

**CHILD DATA**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Waypoints {

@JsonProperty("longitude")
private double longitude;

@JsonProperty("latitude")
private double latitude;

public Waypoints(double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Waypoints() {

}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
 }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MapListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyLatLng, LatLngViewHolder> mRecycleViewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://shining-inferno-2821.firebaseio.com/");
    Query locRef = ref.limitToLast(10);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setReverseLayout(false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    mRecycleViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyLatLng, LatLngViewHolder>(MyLatLng.class, R.layout.list_item, LatLngViewHolder.class, locRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(LatLngViewHolder latLngViewHolder, MyLatLng myLatLng, int i) {

             String key = this.getRef(i).getKey();
             latLngViewHolder.locationA.setText(key);

             latLngViewHolder.locationB.setText(String.valueOf(myLatLng.getWaypoints().get(key).getLongitude()));
             latLngViewHolder.date.setText(String.valueOf(myLatLng.getTimeStamp()));
        }

    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecycleViewAdapter);
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Picture of the wrong key.
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T17I5.png)

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is, but I just took your code and pasted it into an IntelliJ project and it works fine (both on the JSON you included in the question as against what is now in your database). If the problem persists on your side, put a breakpoint on the NPE-throwing line, get the key for that one and try to isolate the problem outside of any view-building.

Comment: I think i've got the wrong key, at myLatLng.getWaypoints().get(key).getLongitude())).  And that i need to access the child key?  But how? I added a picture in the the post above.

Comment: Frank do you have any ideas? Have been trying for hours now, and don't find where it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the key of a `MyLatLng` to try and access a `Waypoints`. Let's rewrite your code a bit so that it's more obvious:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(LatLngViewHolder latLngViewHolder, MyLatLng myLatLng, int i) {
     String myLatLongKey = this.getRef(i).getKey();
     latLngViewHolder.locationA.setText(myLatLongKey);

     WayPoints myWayPoint = myLatLng.getWaypoints().get(myLatLongKey);
     latLngViewHolder.locationB.setText(String.valueOf(myWayPoint.getLongitude()));
     latLngViewHolder.date.setText(String.valueOf(myLatLng.getTimeStamp()));
}
```

Since there is no waypoint with that key (because it's the key of the `MyLatLng`) `Map.get()` returns null and you get a null pointer exception if you try to call methods on that.

I have no idea what your code is meant to do with the waypoints, but you'll want to use operations from the `Map` class to write that code. E.g.

```
String waypointsMsg = "";
for (WayPoints wayPoint: myLatLng.getWaypoints()) {
    waypointsMsg += "("+wayPoint.getLongitude()+","+wayPoint.getLatitude()+")\n";
}
latLngViewHolder.locationB.setText(waypointsMsg);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Frank! I start to understand this better now, thanks again. I also wonder how do I send data from a position from the recyclerview to a second activity. Currently trying to use latLngViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(). But need to figurer out how to pass the clicked items.